# Selenium webdriver test using cloud/remote browser, instead of localhost:4444/wd

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I need to use php-selenium in remote or in web hosting 
need some free services which provide Selenium automation integration like Sauce Labs, BrowserStack its paid services.

Is there any **free service** like http://www.browserstack.com/automate/php

```
$web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub", 
  array("platform"=>"WINDOWS", "browserName"=>"firefox"));
```

which allowed to create live/remote web driver.
or selenium provide any solution for this to run on live server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer

Try out these link 
or make virtual host for running.... :)

Comment: already checked i need some free services which provide Selenium automation integration like Sauce Labs, BrowserStack its paid services.